# Best streaming service for mp4 into webview

Tags: amazon-s3, webview, mp4, amazon-cloudfront

For the welcome screen of my app, we are trying to serve up a webpage in a webview that consists of a video and some text. (We want to go this route so that we could quickly update the welcome screen and test changes on the fly, versus having to submit and get approval each time.)

The video is only 8.6mB and is currently being played via HTML5 , hosted on an S3 and served via CloudFront. However, the playback still tends to be a bit choppy at times. Does anyone have any recommendations as to an optimal way to host and serve up the video to make it play smoothly? Are there any specific settings for the S3 or CloudFront anyone would recommend that could help?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common technique currently is to use ABR in parallel with a CDN to provide smooth playback.

ABR, Adaptive Bit Rate, involves making multiple copies of the video at different bit rates, from low to high and hosting these on the server.

The client receives an index file for the videos, e.g. an m3u8 manifest file, and then chooses the best bit rate for the current conditions to allow smooth playback without buffering.

If network conditions improve the client will 'step up' bit rates and if it gets worse it will 'step down' bit rates.

Typically a low or medium bit rate is chosen as the first one to allow quick and smooth start up.

You can see this effect on services like Netflix as they start up, and you can also see it on YouTube if you right click the video and select 'Stats for Nerds'.

Some links for ABR in AWS Elastic transcoding - you can set the bit rates you want, for e.g. see the note below from their FAQ re HLS jobs:

> Specify that the transcoding job create a playlist that references the outputs. You should order your bit rates from lowest to highest, with the audio only stream last, since this order will be maintained in the generated playlist file. Once your transcoding job has completed, the output bucket will contain a proper arrangement of your master and individual M3U8 playlists, and MPEG-2 TS media stream fragments.

Take a look at the sample request on this page here which includes two different bit rates (video service providers will generally have more than 2 but this gives you a feel for the approach):

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/create-job.html

Comment: Mick, thanks for the response. So on AWS, is ABR the equivalent of their Elastic Transcoder service? I was starting to play with that, but had some trouble understanding if I had set it up correctly, and then what the actual HTML code looks like (in the <video> tag am I just posting the .m3u8 file path and that's it?).

Comment: Elastic Transcode is the genera term for the AWS transcoding service, but it does support ABR - if you search for ABR and HLS bit rates along with AWS elastic transcoding you should see some examples, but I'll add one in the answer also. The .m3u8 path is what you use as the src for the video tag, as you note, for HTMl5.

Comment: Sorry, still figuring this out as I go. Is there a list of what outputs (and in what order) I should be selecting when I create the Outputs for the Playlist? I was starting with HLS Video - 2M, but not sure of exactly which (and how many) outputs I really need.

Comment: There is no absolute rule - most commercial operators that provide an OTT (internet based) video streaming service will provide between 5 and 8 bit rates from lowest to highest but the transcoding costs add up so you may not want that many. If you just have one video and it does not change that much then its not such an overhead so more bit rates is maybe not such an expense.

Comment: Mick, thanks again for all your help with this. I thought I had everything set up correctly:
1. have initial mp4 in an S3 bucket
2. set up Elastic Transcoding of mp4 file, creating a pipeline and a job that creates a playlist outputting 600k, 1M, 1.5M, 2M HLS files (in that order) back to an S3 bucket

I see the generated .ts and .m3u8 file in that bucket. However, when I use the path to that .m3u8 file in my <video> tag src, nothing plays and on inspection I get a status 403 failed to load resource error. I ck'd the permissions, and everything is Read enabled. Any addt'l thoughts?

Comment: I'd say probably best to open another question and include the m3u8 and the browser console - it could be a number of things, like the correct url format in the m3u8 but it will be easier to say with the extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Media Services has a built in "Adaptive Streaming" preset that is content-adaptive and can adjust the encoding settings to meet your content that is coming in. 
See the following - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-autogen-bitrate-ladder-with-mes